# Do combined waves with non-rational frequencies have a common period?

Tags: harmonic-analysis, signal-processing, wave-equation

I am facing a problem where I have two waves combined:
\begin{equation}
y = A\sin(b_1x)+B\cos(b_2x)
\end{equation}
Where $ b_1 $ and $ b_2 $ are non-rationals. i.e. \begin{align}
 & b_1 = \sqrt{3+\sqrt{5}}  
&  b_2 = \sqrt{3-\sqrt{5}} \end{align}

I wanted to know if there exists $ X_p $ such that $ y(x+X_p) = y(x) $.
I am confused here because if I actually try to solve this equation, the common procedure is to do the following:
\begin{align}
 & y(x+X_p) = y(x) \\ 
&  A\sin(b_1(x+X_p))+B\cos(b_2(x+X_p)) = A\sin(b_1x+2\pi n)+B\cos(b_2x+2\pi m ) \\
& \forall n,m \in \mathbb{N}  \end{align}
This will give 2 equations in $X_p$ , $n$ and $m$ if the sine and cosine are equated separately. However, I could not see a solution to that and I start to doubt whether a solution exists at all...

EDIT:

I am doubting a solution that can be applied to any A and B.

Thank you!

Comment: The frequencies themselves are not really important. It is their _ratio_, $b_1\over b_2$, that matters. If it is rational, there would be common period. If not, not.

Comment: Is there a theorem that says so I can access? I am saying it  only because of intuitive feeling. I understand the fact that in order to be able to solve this in the manner I suggested above, you condition must be true. However, I cannot see this wave as an ever changing wave (without any periodic basis what so ever...)

Comment: Why, there is a theorem, and it can fit in one comment (if not in one twit). Suppose there is such $X_p$. Then $b_1X_p=2\pi n$, $b_2X_p=2\pi m$, so ${b_1\over b_2}={b_1X_p\over b_2X_p}={2\pi n\over2\pi m}={n\over m}$, which is rational, which we just assumed it is not.

Comment: @IvanNeretin You could write an answer so that the OP can accept it and remove the question from the unanswered (long...) list.